# How to get item height of ListView without using OnItemClickListener?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I use this piece of code to vertically center selected item of ListView;

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
    m_listView.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position, (m_listView.getHeight() - v.getHeight()) / 2, 100);
}
```

There is no problem with this. Problem is I can't center the default selected item because I can't get neither ListView height nor item height.

What I tried;

- Creating views with `Inflater` (returns 0 as height)
- Running `performClick()` method on default selected item (does nothing, throws no exception)

So what can I do?

Note: Item heights are equal.

Comment: try this:View listItem = listAdapter.getView(item Number, null, listView);
                        listItem.measure(0, 0); 
                        int list_child_item_height = listItem.getMeasuredHeight()+listView.getDividerHeight();

Comment: `There is no problem with this.` what is the problem then ?

Comment: @zt9788 This works, but how to get ListView height? I tried `ListView.measure(0, 0);` then `getHeight()` but still returns 0.

Comment: @njzk2 The code only works when an item clicked. I need this just after creation of ListView.

Comment: @m_poorUser I post answer

Comment: you have to call this when you listview is visible. That is probably around onAttachedToWindow in your activity, or maybe in onWindowFocusChanged

Comment: @njzk2 It worked, put your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

take this code:

```
//
int totalHeight = 0;//it is the ListView Height
for (int i = 0, len = listAdapter.getCount(); i < len; i++) {
    View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
    listItem.measure(0, 0);
    int list_child_item_height = listItem.getMeasuredHeight()+listView.getDividerHeight();//item height
    totalHeight += list_child_item_height; //
}
```

Comment: Items are in a scroll, so (item count * item height) != (listview height).

Comment: @m_poorUser I can't imagine what is like? ListView{Scroll{item}}?

Comment: ListView already scrollable, I don't have to put a ScrollView inside it. Anyway, @njzk2's answer is worked. I used same code but just inside onWindowFocusChanged listener assigned to my ListView.